# Show icon in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I want to get an image from server and show in action bar instead of icon.
I wrote below code and tested and worked well in android 4.2 but when i installed my application in android 6.0.1, not showed.

```
getActionBar().setTitle("test");
getActionBar().setIcon(icon);
```

The android 6.0.1 version changed title with `setTitle()` code but can't add icon in my actionbar.

I  tested `setLogo` method but not worked.
How can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("test");

    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    assert ab != null;
    //ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo1);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks but, toolbarMain cant resolve symbol and i don't know what is this!!

Comment: this is you toolbar id check in xml file

Answer (score 0):

try following code , may help you.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```